# selecting certain char in string not working properly PHP

Tags: php

I have a link:

www.site.com?something=thisismystring

now:

```
$bd=$_GET['something'];
$c=3;

echo $bd{$c};
```

Now when I try that, i get the forth char printed on screen, not the third, so then i try to add one up on `$c` to just check I'm doing it right (`$c=4`). And again, that returns the 5th char of the string when it should return the 4th....

I know this is something i'm doing wrong, but i cannot figure out what.

all help is much appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nav,

The array starts at 0.

**So for your example:**
www.site.com?something=thisismystring

$bd=$_GET['something'];
$c=0;

echo $bd{$c};

That would print out the letter t (first character of the string).

Answer (score 5):

Strings, and pretty much everything else in most programming languages, work with a **0-based index**. The index of the *first* item is 0, the *second* item is 1 and so on...

Answer (score 3):

When string treated like array the first index of it = 0 
so if you want to get the third character you must use

```
$bd=$_GET['something'];
$c=2;

echo $bd{$c};
```

Answer (score 2):

Character indexes, along with array indexes, [start at 0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), not 1.  Therefore, to get the *nth* character in a string, its index would be *n - 1*.